# Karma keeps disconnecting with error -- TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'xxxx')

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Karma keeps failing and disconnecting with the following error

```
26 04 2023 08:10:56.565:ERROR [karma-server]: TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'manual-3315')
    at initliazeXmlForBrowser (C:\Users\mi872f\Documents\dev\configo-ui\node_modules\karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter\index.js:51:41)
    at SonarQubeUnitReporter.onBrowserStart (C:\Users\mi872f\Documents\dev\configo-ui\node_modules\karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter\index.js:117:5)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mi872f\Documents\dev\configo-ui\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:40:26)
    at Server.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Browser.onStart (C:\Users\mi872f\Documents\dev\configo-ui\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:84:18)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mi872f\Documents\dev\configo-ui\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:214:39)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emitUntyped (C:\Users\mi872f\Documents\dev\configo-ui\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:69:22)
    at C:\Users\mi872f\Documents\dev\configo-ui\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:466:39
Firefox 102.0 (Windows 10) ERROR
Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (transport close)
Firefox 102.0 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 193 DISCONNECTED (2.032 secs / 0 secs)
```

The tests do successfully run prior to getting this error, but then it always disconnects, making it difficult to debug the tests. It always reads either `(setting 'manual-3315')` or `(setting '88262020')`

`karma.conf.js:`

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
    plugins: [
      require("karma-jasmine"),
      require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
      require("karma-firefox-launcher"),
      require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
      require("karma-coverage"),
      require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma"),
      require('karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter'),
    ],
    sonarQubeUnitReporter: {
      sonarQubeVersion: 'LATEST',
      outputFile: 'reports/configoUnitTestReport.xml',
      overrideTestDescription: true,
      useBrowserName: false
    },
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
      },
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true, // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require("path").join(__dirname, "./coverage"),
      subdir: ".",
      reporters: [
        { type: "html" },
        { type: "lcov", subdir: "report-lcov" },
      ],
    },
    reporters: ["progress",'sonarqubeUnit',"kjhtml"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Firefox"],
    customLaunchers: {
      Headless: {
        base: "ChromeHeadless",
        flags: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
        prefs: {
          "network.proxy.type": 0,
        },
      },
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

Even deactivating the source-map when running the test doesn't seem to help